# ERRO- MS Access 2013 - Nenhum índice exclusivo encontrado para o campo referenciado da tabela primária

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Estou aprendendo MS Access 2013 e tento criar relationships com 3 tabelas. Quando as relaciono sem a opção Enforce Referential Integrity a relação é gerada, contudo, quando coloco a mesma opção obtenho o erro:

> "nenhum índice exclusivo encontrado para o campo referenciado da tabela primária"

Comment: Como estão suas tabelas? Pode dar mais informações, editando sua pergunta?